# How to capture all wrapped text of multiple paragraph tags in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am facing one problem . I made a function for capturing the value of paragraph tag  . For a single paragraph its perfectly working but there are so many paragraph tags . How can i retrieve these values in a function ?

```
public String captureText(WebDriver driver) {
    String captureValue;
    captureValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Subtitles']//following::p[1]")).getText();
    return captureValue;

}
```

My function is looking like above.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code :

```
//create a list to store all the paragraph text values
//Store all the paragraphs element in another list
public List<String> captureText(WebDriver driver) {

    List<String> allParagraphsValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<WebElement> allParagraphs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[text()='Subtitles']//following::p"));

    //Loop through all the Paragraph elements and add the text in a list
    for(WebElement ele : allParagraphs){
          allParagraphsValues.add(ele.getText());
    }

    return allParagraphsValues;

}
```

Comment: Thank you @kovid mehta. I followed the same process what you have shared .